# Have can I call the property(function) of the specified namespace with javascript cross different page?Asp.net Ajax or node.js is good solution?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, node.js, namespaces

In the admin web application site, Any way to make me use the same namespace javascript object in different page?for example, the first page is login page,if I create the javascript object, like below:

```
var App = {
    username:"Tom",
    password:"1234",
    initLoginUI:function(){

        ......   

    },
    initPageUI:function(){
        ......
    }
}
```

After I login, I direct to index.html page, I want to call App.initPageUI() in index.html, is it impossible? How should I do that, could javascript expert give me some suggestion? Many Thanks!

**Update:**

I find one way is very close what I mean:

http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/bmains/archive/2009/05/30/ajax-and-type-registernamespace-how-it-works.aspx

It is Asp.Net Ajax, but if I don't know Asp.net, I only want to use javascript, maybe..... node.js??? But how to use node.js in my case?I want to some example.....I don't know too much about node.js...but I want to learn!!Or any popular(fancy) framework I can use?

Please give me any good suggestion, Many Thanks:)

Comment: May be possible with cookies(not sure). Otherwise you have to send data to server and fetch them back.

Comment: Thank @plbsam ! I will try this way, but I still want to know if in the front end side,is ti possible

Comment: What you're looking for is called single page web applications, which are pretty famous nowadays.

Comment: mmmm,,,, you mean different page,but direct page to the same url?how should I do to attempt that?